# IIS Hosted service and Windows firewall issue

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I've got an IIS hosted WCF service running at port 8081 on a machine running Windows Server 2008R2, which works fine when Windows Firewall is disabled. But I've ran into some problems when trying to get it to work with the firewall enabled.

I've added a firewall rule for port 8081 and firewall enabled. In this case a remote computer can not get access to the service.

If I then disable the firewall, do a request to the service, and then re-enable the firewall, it works fine with the firewall enabled. But if I remove the rule after re-enabling the firewall, it stops working again.

So to get access I have to add the rule, disable the firewall, access the service with the firewall disabled, and then re-enable the firewall with the rule created.

How can I get it to work through the firewall without having to access the service with the firewall disabled?

Comment: It seems to work when I enable File and Printer sharing as well.. Anyone have an idea as to why this one is needed?

Comment: Just like other bugs that MS has, so challenging.  I couldn't get mine working either.  But it works when i moved the whole WCF out to another computer which has the same setting as the one who couldn't work with. Why it works?  Lost me!

Answer (score 1):

1- Open "Windows Firewall with advanced security"

2- Go to Inbound Rules and add the ports one by one:

```
1- 8888 – TeamPulse Client Site
2- 9899 – TeamPulse Synchronizaton Service
3- 8734 – TeamPulse Synchronization Service
4- 2431 – TeamPulse User Administraton Sit
```